# Nuget dependency management (internal/private source)

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have my own Nuget package source for internal libraries.  Some of the projects reference other projects in the same solution.  Currently the dependencies are referenced to the Nuget package.  Management of this be becoming a pain since if a project that has a dependency is updated, I have to wait for that dependency package to update so I can update the other project with the new reference.  Some of the projects have multiple layers of dependency, so in some cases I to wait for 5 builds (build, update package, build, update package in next level, etc.) to get the package into the main project.  Is there a better way to manage this or is this just the price to pay for using Nuget?

Comment: Did you install the library into your main project via NuGet and also add the library's project to the same solution?

Comment: Say I have Company.Core and Company.NewStuff as Nuget packages and NewStuff depends on Core.  If I reference Core in the NewStuff package as a project reference and Core's version is lower than NewStuff, the package can't be found when add it via NuGet to the main project.  So Core was added to NewStuff via Nuget as a workaround.  Which is what is causing the management issues.  Now when Core is updated every project that are our Nuget packages have to be updated.  And then all of the packages have dependencies on those packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't include your libraries in the solution for a given application and only add them to the solution via NuGet.  You can manage versioning between the NuGet Packages in the packages.config file of a given library and by referencing [NuGet Package versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning).

When I have a situation where I need to step through the library code from the consuming application then I remove the NuGet package and add the library project to the solution.  Then add a project reference from the application to that library project.  Ideally this should be a rare occurrence.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it is what it is.  Hopefully they make it easier in the future.